# AS3 Hide Random Object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm relatively new to AS3, and currently trying to figure out a solution to this problem:

I've got a launch screen of 25 icons (movie clips, but just static images) in a grid, with buttons behind them. On rollover of each of the icons, I'd like a random selection of the 25 icons to be hidden - EXCEPT for the icon currently rolled over. Then on ROLL_OUT, all 25 icons should become visible again.

Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your current code? That will give us something to build upon.

Comment: Share your current code and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is to loop through all the MoveiClips you have and randomly select some to be set to be invisible.

To make the MovieClips invisible we will set their `visible` property to `false` which will hide them.

Since you have no supplied us with any of your current code, I will attempt to create some to fit your needs.

```
function icon_rollOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < holderMC.numChildren; i++) {
        if (holderMC.getChildAt(i) != e.target) {
            holderMC.getChildAt(i).visible = Math.random() > 0.5;
        }
    }
}

function icon_rollOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < holderMC.numChildren; i++) {
        holderMC.getChildAt(i).visible = true;
    }
}

// Add icon_rollOver and icon_rollOut as events to each of your MovieClips
```

That code should do the trick. I'm not currently in a position where I can test the code however, so there may be an error or two; however that is the basic principle.

`holderMC` is the MovieClip where each of the icons is stored. If there are other MovieClips inside this `holderMC` that are not icons, then some slightly more complex code would be needed, or for these non-icons to be moved into another container.

When the `icon_rollOver` function is called, it will loop over every MovieClip inside `holderMC` and then check to see if it is the same as `e.target` where `e` is the event. The `target` property refers to the object that dispatched the event, so in this case should be the MovieClip that was rolled over. If the current child is NOT the one where have rolled over, then set it's visibility to a conditional equating to whether a random number (between 0 and 1) is greater than .5. I.E. there is a 50% chance the MovieClip will be made invisible.

When the `icon_rollOut` function is called, we again loop over every MovieClip inside `holderMC` but then just set the visibility to be true no matter what. This will make EVERY MovieClip in `holderMC` visible.

I hope that is enough to help you with your project. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the .visible property that exists in every movie clip.
One easy example is:

```
MyMovieClip.visible = false;
```

This would make the movieclip invisible when called.

One possible solution to your problem would be making an array of movieclips that you detoggled/toggled on ROLL_OVER and on ROLL_OUT.